# Retrofit 2 request doesn't give me data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to send a GET request through Retrofit 2.

However, the request doesn't do anything..

**API SERVICE**

```
package com.example.brews.network

import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

/*
    This is the sandbox base url (way less data than production environment)
    When deploying app -> use production base url
 */
private const val BASE_URL = "https://sandbox-api.brewerydb.com/v2/"

/**
 * Build the Moshi object that Retrofit will be using, making sure to add the Kotlin adapter for
 * full Kotlin compatibility.
 */
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

/**
 * Use the Retrofit builder to build a retrofit object using a Moshi converter with our Moshi
 * object.
 */
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

/**
 * A public interface that exposes the [getProperties] method
 */
interface BreweryApiService {
    /**
     * Returns a Coroutine [Deferred] [List] of [BeerProperty] which can be fetched with await() if
     * in a Coroutine scope.
     * The @GET annotation indicates that the "beers" endpoint will be requested with the GET
     * HTTP method
     */
    @GET("beers/")
    fun getProperties(@Query("?key") key: String):
    // The Coroutine Call Adapter allows us to return a Deferred, a Job with a result
            Deferred<List<BeerProperty>>

}

/**
 * A public Api object that exposes the lazy-initialized Retrofit service
 */
object BreweryApi {
    val retrofitService: BreweryApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(BreweryApiService::class.java) }
}
```

**DATA CLASS**

```
package com.example.brews.network

data class BeerProperty(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

**Method that fills up my list**

```
private fun getBeersProperties() {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        var getPropertiesDeferred =
            BreweryApi.retrofitService.getProperties("13e9caaf80adac04dce90ef55600d898")
        try {
            _status.value = BreweryApiStatus.LOADING
            val listResult = getPropertiesDeferred.await()
            _status.value = BreweryApiStatus.DONE
            _properties.value = listResult
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _status.value = BreweryApiStatus.ERROR
            _properties.value = ArrayList()
        }
    }
}
```

**The JSON retrieved by the link**

{
    "currentPage": 1,
    "numberOfPages": 23,
    "totalResults": 1109,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "c4f2KE",
            "name": "'Murican Pilsner",
            "nameDisplay": "'Murican Pilsner",
            "abv": "5.5",
            "glasswareId": 4,
            "styleId": 98,
            "isOrganic": "N",
            "isRetired": "N"
        }
            ]
}

What I need to retrieve is the 'ID' and 'Name' inside the 'Data'. However, this is in an array and I don't know how to extract it with retrofit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a DAO object to get the JSON response from retrofit and then parse the JSON object to get the result you want.

So create a DAO object like this:-

```
data class BeerResponse(
  val data: List<BeerProperty>?
)
```

And change your service method to:-

```
@GET("beers/")
fun getProperties(@Query("?key") key: String):
// The Coroutine Call Adapter allows us to return a Deferred, a Job with a result
        Deferred<BeerResponse>
```

Then in your getBeerProperties method, change it to this:-

```
private fun getBeersProperties() {
coroutineScope.launch {
    var getPropertiesDeferred =
        BreweryApi.retrofitService.getProperties("13e9caaf80adac04dce90ef55600d898")
    try {
        _status.value = BreweryApiStatus.LOADING
        val listResult = getPropertiesDeferred.await()
        listResult.data?.let {
            _status.value = BreweryApiStatus.DONE
            _properties.value = it
        } ?: let {
            _status.value = BreweryApiStatus.ERROR
            _properties.value = ArrayList()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        _status.value = BreweryApiStatus.ERROR
        _properties.value = ArrayList()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your implementation of the network API is wrong and should change to this

```
data class BeerProperty(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)

data class Response(
  val data: List<BeerProperty>?
)

interface BreweryApiService {
    @GET("beers/")
    fun getProperties(@Query("?key") key: String):
            Deferred<Response>
}
```

you could also put the number of pages, current page and ... in the Response class
also, you can use JSON to kotlin class plugin in android studio to make these data classes faster and with fewer mistakes, you can also use websites like [this](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print) to see the JSON in prety format which is more readable